Remove Admin permissions from Configurator enrolled user
I'm trying to enroll MacOS devices to Intune with Apple configurator, so far have done all the setups that will Enroll with User Affinity but user account that get created get admin privileges by default, is there any way to restrict this to standard user ?
Thank you
